# Run Explorer as the Admin Account In the Standard User's Environment

Tags: windows, batch-file, explorer

This is more of a pet project, as I like to try my best to batch script whatever I feel like without using a 3rd party app. I understand it would be easier that way, but I want to just try this for the heck of it. I understand the basic issue might just be the way the shell executes explorer, as I know it was NOT intended to run like this.

I have a standard user account and a batch script:

```
@echo OFF
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`hostname`) DO SET COMPNAME=%%i
ECHO Computer %COMPNAME%
TASKKILL /F /IM explorer.exe
runas /user:"%COMPNAME%"\ADMIN "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"
Echo.
Echo Press Enter once you are finished
Pause
TASKKILL /F /IM explorer.exe
explorer.exe
Exit
```

Basically each computer's name is the hostname of the computer, so I created a variable to process that. Then I have it kill explorer, then run CMD as the admin account. (I can replace this with Explorer as well.) Then when CMD opens I type explorer.exe and it opens the admin account with full access. The script runs fine, no issues at all with the script. But in regards to the environment, there are 2 issues I am running into.

1. Windows 7 everything works fine, every program I open is ADMIN, even the start menu user profile title at the top right of the start menu says ADMIN, until I open Administrative tools, then every application I open from there uses the standard user, such as computer management. I assume explorer processes the command off of the local user environment which is why. I know I can just use compmgmt as an admin to solve that, but I want to know the specific reason why Explorer is swapping, is it as simple as the shell uses the local environment and that is just how it is?
2. On Windows 10, the script process successfully, but Explorer runs extremely slow. Every other program runs fine, cmd, compmgmt, regedit, Firefox, etc... But Explorer is slow, I'm talking 5 minutes to open the favorites window, and the start menu will not open at all. I checked process explorer and nothing takes it up, except the standard get resolution and other graphic handles. I assume it might be just the way this Shell operates.

Anyway, I understand this is not ideal, and that there are far easier ways to do it, and that Explorer.exe was never intended to be run like this. I just wanted to try for my own personal creativity. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: In Windows 8 the charms bar and all that stuff lives in Explorer and Explorer is actually a Metro/Modern application in some respects. In Windows 10 things are even worse and there are at least 3 processes involved when you interact with the start menu.

Comment: @Anders, if you kill those processes in Windows 10 (e.g. the shell infrastructure host, sihost.exe), they'll be restarted as the session user, which is cached by the Local Session Manager service (e.g. `WTSQueryUserToken`). But that doesn't explain the problem in Windows 7. Administrative tools require admin access, and I assume this "ADMIN" user requires elevation. The Application Information (Appinfo) service that runs consent.exe and creates the elevated process should query the caller's token to get the associated elevated token. It works (very slowly) in Windows 10.